# Is pgtune still valid for newer PostgreSQL versions?

Tags: postgresql, performance, database-tuning, postgresql-performance

Since [pgtune](https://github.com/gregs1104/pgtune) has not been updated since more than 4 years ago, should it still be used with newer PostgreSQL versions? (say, >=9.3)

What about the [online version](http://pgtune.leopard.in.ua/)?

Comment: This would be good to ask the [maintainer](https://github.com/le0pard) of the online version.

Comment: @LowlyDBA I'm sorry, is that the reason for the downvote?

Comment: Yes, it seems unlikely that the old version will work 100% properly with a new version and since the online version has an active maintainer who has chosen to not document version compatibility, you might as well just ask him directly.

Comment: `Latest commit 515b7bd Jun 2, 2015`

Comment: @LowlyDBA Isn't Stackexchange about collecting answers to questions that may be interesting to more than one person? :)

Comment: @SahapAsci That commit is mostly cosmetic, "Still needs some work before a newer version can actually be targeted"

Comment: @Joril For sure, but questions regarding specific versions of random third party tools and their compatibility with specific versions of DBs can quickly become obsolete or incorrect and have questionable value when the tool (or this case, fork of one) isn't ubiquitously used.

Answer (score 2):

There is an active fork of [PgTune maintained here](https://github.com/le0pard/pgtune). That said, I don't know of anyone that uses it.

Comment: This is a dead link.  :(

Comment: @dviljoen updated